# Are there Hash Arrays in Delphi?

Tags: java, arrays, perl, delphi, hash

Im learning Delphi but loved to use hash arrays in Perl and Java. Are there compairing data structures in Delphi?

I know that It is possible to use TStringList as a Hash Array :

```
var 
   myHash:TStringList);

begin 

  myHash:=TStringList.Create();
  myHash.values['color']:='blue';

  Showmessage(myHash.Values['color']);  //blue   

  myHash.free;

end;
```

Is it possible to build more complicated data structures like Perl's hash of arrays etc. in Delphi?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using Delphi 2009 or later (and hopefully later, because there was a serious bug in the original implementation) you can find the `TDictionary` class in the `Generics.Collections` unit.  `TDictionar<TKey, TValue>` functions as a hash-map of keys to values, which should be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Fortunately there are workarounds for Generics.Collection bugs in Delphi 2009 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216733 was the most serious iirc). (I only use very basic generic collection functionality)

Comment: So there is no TDictionary class in Delphi 7, which I have to work at work?

Comment: @user3133542: No, it was introduced in D2009.